# Can't install created nuget package- The dependency XY 1.0.0 does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

Tags: nuget, .net-core, nuget-package

My Project XY is targeting .NET Standard 1.3 and contains the following dependencies:

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
    "System.Data.Common": "4.3.0",
    "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.3.0",
    "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.3.0",
    "System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml": "4.3.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.3": {
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using NuGet Version: `3.5.0.1938` with the following command: nuget pack XY.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects which works fine.

When installing the created nuget package to a .NET Core Console Application (or UWP) Project, it will fail with the error message:

> package XY 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0
>   (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package XY 1.0.0 supports: portable50
>   (portable50,Version=v0.0) error: One or more packages are incompatible
>   with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.

I don't know from where "portable50" is coming. Also I can't find with Nuget Package Explorer something with "portable50".

[image]

Please note, I can add the XY .netstandard project as reference to the NETCoreApp solution and use it. It seems that the nuget package manager does something wrong?